# Reinstall drupal after deleting database, install.php says already installed

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I'm trying to get Drupal 7.28 installed on Ubuntu and have run into this very common but not so easily fixed issue of the WSOD during configuration due to the database not being properly set up on an earlier step (only 31 tables created). https://www.drupal.org/node/481758

Many people have fixed this issue by dropping the database and recreating it, which I've tried, but when I try to run /install.php again it insists that it is already installed and I must empty the database if I want to reinstall.

So I tried deleting the database and NOT recreating it but the installer still says it is already installed and I have to empty the database WHICH DOES NOT EXIST if I want to reinstall.

What do I need to do to get the install script to run again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh. I needed to go back to the default settings.php for the site, then it worked.

in /var/www/drupal/sites/mysite.com

```
mv settings.php old_settings.php
cp default.settings.php settings.php
```

Now going to mysite.com/install.php starts over at the beginning of the install.